# Effect on SEO if I keep images in different domain?

Tags: seo, images, image-hosting

This question is related to another question that I asked earier: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558410/how-to-not-send-a-cookie-to-a-subdomain.

It seems like, I have to put all my images to another domain. My site is an image sharing site and I am concerned that it may adversely affect the SEO of the website.

Is there any way to tell Google that both the domains are related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Does Google consider the URL of an image?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h2SWuUobbr0)
- [How Google works with images](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sj5Ny21q3oY)

[Google Webmaster help Youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/GoogleWebmasterHelp)

Comment: Might be more helpful if you include a summary of the info instead of just links (especially when those links are videos).  Aside from the general guidelines on Stack Exchange that link-only answers are discouraged, videos/sound may not be appropriate for various workplace environments.

Comment: The content in these videos addresses filenames and metadata of images helping Google to process images, but doesn't really touch on the issue of domain names at all.

Answer (score 3):

How Google classifies your images is using `alt` tags, using a `title` tag for your images, image captions, naming images...

It makes sense from which domain user is getting redirected to actual content he/she looking for...

So if user goes to image and press back button to come back to original domain, then it creates wrong impression for your site. so you should open that image URL in another tab only. It might solve your some problem.

Comment: User wont be accessing images directly. Images will open as img tag inside several pages.